# Configuring a htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to develope a codeigniter application and when I run it on my xampp everything works perfectly but when I run it on the server on 1and1 I get an error 500.

I have talked with 1and1 and they say, the problem is with this htaccess and I don't understand why?.

This is the file:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
 </IfModule>
<Files "index.php">
   AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>  

php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value max_execution_time 30
php_value max_input_time 30
```

Where is the problem?. Thanks so much

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: I can't see them because it's a shared server, so 1and1 doesn't let see apache logs.

Comment: Try removing php_values , your host may have disabled them. See if it works without them.

Comment: @Charly66 - then they should be able to tell you exactly what the cause of the problem is, because they have access to the logs themselves...

Answer (score 0):

In 1and1 you couldn't change the server php specifications like:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value max_execution_time 30
php_value max_input_time 30
```

Try removing this lines.

Also, this is my .htaccess file working on 1and1 server:

```
#Deny from all
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^core.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If the CI installation is in another folder relative to .htaccess, you should change the RewriteBase / to /CI-folder